# Panda csv with json parse and filter

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with CSV files where one of the column have a json object (data column):

```
col1;col2;data;col3;col4
aaa;bbb;{'ccc': 'ddd', 'labels': {'label1':'value_a','label2':'value_b'}};xxx;yyy
eee;fff;{'ggg': 'hhh', 'labels': {'label1':'value_c','label3':'value_d'}};zzz;ooo
```

I wan't to generate a new filtered csv like this (with the keys/values of the json) :

```
 label1;label2;label3
 value_a;value_b;
 value_c;value_d;
```

My code now :

```
df = pd.read_csv(mycsv_file, sep=";", usecols=["data"])
df["data"] = df["data"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df_json = pd.DataFrame(
    df["data"].tolist(),
)
print(df["data"][0]["labels"])

#out
{'label1': 'foo', 'label2': 'bar'}
```

do I have to iterate over all the lines, or is there a smarter way?

Comment: Please make your example non ambiguous which foo/bar in the input are those of the output?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. i updated my example... I hope it's less ambiguous

Comment: Are you sure about your example? In your csv sample, separator is comma, not semi-column. It is not possible for pd.read_csv to make the difference between the commas separating the fields and the ones separating the values in the json like column

Comment: @Nico, thanks, but it's unfortunately invalid CSV, are you sure the JSON is not escaped? How did you produce it? If your JSON is in "data", what are col3/col4?

Comment: I've tried to simplify the dataset, I'm only interested in the json keys and values (col3, col4 are unnecessary data)..

Comment: Why is value_d in column label2 in your required output ?

Comment: Do you know all of the labels you want in advance? Dataframes are great, but they can eat a lot of memory, especially when you've got embedded python objects. You could use the regular `csv` module and do the read/write line by line. That may perform better for your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have successfully converted the JSON strings in the '`data`' column into Python dictionaries.

then, you can proceed to extract the required values and create a new DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(mycsv_file, sep=",")

# Convert the 'data' column from JSON strings to Python dictionaries
df["data"] = df["data"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Extract the labels and values
all_labels = set()
for row in df["data"]:
    if "labels" in row:
        all_labels.update(row["labels"].keys())

# Convert the set of labels to a list to maintain order
label_columns = list(all_labels)

# Create a new DataFrame with columns for each unique label
df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(columns=label_columns)

# Fill in the values based on the 'labels' in each 'data' row
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if "labels" in row["data"]:
        label_values = row["data"]["labels"]
        df_filtered = df_filtered.append(label_values, ignore_index=True)

# Save the filtered DataFrame to a new CSV file
df_filtered.to_csv("filtered_output.csv", index=False)
```

Approach 2: Without iterating on df rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
from pandas import json_normalize

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(mycsv_file, sep=",")

# Convert the 'data' column from JSON strings to Python dictionaries
df["data"] = df["data"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Use json_normalize to flatten the 'labels' column
df_normalized = json_normalize(df["data"].apply(lambda x: x.get("labels", {})))

# Save the normalized DataFrame to a new CSV file
df_normalized.to_csv("filtered_output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: OP asked for a solution without iterating on df rows

Comment: Added second approach with solution without iterating on df rows, please check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping not to have to iterate on the df row.
I tried your example but it returned an error when `df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(columns=labels)` : `raise ValueError("columns cannot be a set") ValueError: columns cannot be a set`

Comment: @Nico, please check updated first approach: with iterate on the df row and also please check second approach: with solution without iterating on df rows. Let me know if any error occur

Comment: @TheHungryCub : same error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../main.py", line 89, in <module>
    out_file = parse_file(projects_file)
  File "/.../main.py", line 29, in parse_file
    df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(columns=labels)
  File "/..../lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 702, in __init__
    raise ValueError("columns cannot be a set")
ValueError: columns cannot be a set`

Comment: @Nico `df["data"].apply` just hides the iteration over rows by moving it inside the `apply` call. Unfortunately, `object` dtypes aren't very well supported for vectorization by pandas.

Comment: @TheHungryCub I've now come across quite a few of your answers (deleted and undeleted) in the wild. and I see that people quite frequently complain that the answer doesn't work / produces the same error they originally asked about. Please note that you should verify that your answer is actually helpful before posting it. I've also seen that people copying their code from ChatGPT or similar frequently get their first (few) tries at an answer wrong. If that is what you're doing, you should know that [use of generative AI in answers is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/843953)

Comment: @pho Thank you for your suggestion. I will make sure that I will verify the output first at my end then add it as answer. Thanks again!